# I can't read data from the client

Tags: c#, sockets

For educational purposes, I am writing a program that passes through a SQL queries.  It should work like this:

[image]

But Receive does not return any data.

```
private static byte[] ReadToEnd(Socket mySocket)
{
  byte[] b = new byte[mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
  int len = 0;
  using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
  {
      while (mySocket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead) &&
                (len = mySocket.Receive(b, mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
      {
          m.Write(b, 0, len);
          Console.WriteLine("Я тут");
      }
      Console.WriteLine("и тут");
      return m.ToArray();

   }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener myTCP = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888));
    Console.WriteLine("Прослушиваю порт");
    while (true)
    {   
        myTCP.Start(); // Запускаю процесс прослушивания
        if (myTCP.Pending()) // Если есть запрос
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Соединение добавлено в очередь");
            using (Socket myClient = myTCP.AcceptSocket()) // То создаю сокет для этого запроса
            {
                if (myClient.Connected) // Если сокет открыт, то считываю поток байтов от клиента
                {

                        Console.WriteLine("Открываю сокет для считывания запроса");
                        byte[] sqlQuery = new byte[myClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                        sqlQuery = ReadToEnd(myClient);    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post that as an answer :)

Comment: remembers all the SQL queries sent to the server in any program, something like a proxy server

Comment: As TCP packets split at `MTU`, I suggest adding something like a length to the packet first (like the first 4 bytes), then read until you got the amount of bytes you need. This way, are not stalling your program until it has all info.

Comment: I wrote the client http://pastebin.com/Ht6BcfXK sending the request to the port that listens for my program. Tell me why while (mySocket.Poll(1000000,SelectMode.SelectRead) &&n(len = mySocket.Receive(b, mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None)) > 0) is false?

Comment: SelectMode.SelectRead return false